# How to recover records, deleted by accident, from SQL server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to recover records, deleted by accident, from SQL server 2005? Any suggestions?

Comment: [Join the club ;-)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347190/whats-your-biggest-fear-as-a-programmer/3347302#3347302)

Answer (score 3):

Even if the database is set in SIMPLE recovery model, if lost data are from period before DBA created a backup, data could be easily retrieved with Tools like Data diff, directly from the backup and quite painless and fast. For large amount of data from different tables it was cheaper to get a tool than to waste days to locate and get the data back.
[How to recover only individual rows from backups](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/2012/11/how-to-recover-only-individual-rows_16.html)

In case of using FULL recovery model, and vanished data dates from the period after the last backup creation, than you can retrieve data from t-log
[How to recover SQL Server data from accidental UPDATE and DELETE operations](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/2012/11/how-to-recover-sql-server-data-from.html)

Just, it have to be calculated which one is more expensive... time spent on recovering of data or price of Tool. If time loss is not directly the money loss, than no need for any third party tool.

In our case, Time is much, much more expensive than third party tool we are using, so it's obvious what we opted for.

Answer (score 2):

If your database is in full recovery mode then it is possible to restore it back in time.
Otherwise you need to restore a backup to get that data back.

Read this article: [How to: Restore to a Point in Time (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982.aspx)

Comment: Curses, you beat me to it. ;)

Comment: @Andy Evans Hahah! :) There's nothing like competition, eh?

Answer (score 1):

This article may provide some useful information for you. If you don't have a backup that contains the records you need I don't believe there's much you can do.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/sql-server-2005-backups/